# PostgresSQL dump loading succeed but nothing is written on the database

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-18.04

I've try to load a dump to a new database and all seems to work :

```
user@vpsXXXX:~$ pg_dump -U user -d database < mydump.sql
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 10.6 (Ubuntu 10.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 10.6 (Ubuntu 10.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

--
-- Name: plpgsql; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner: 
--

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;


--
-- Name: EXTENSION plpgsql; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner: 
--

COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

When I look the tables on a software like Postico, there is no tables except the Postgres ones. My dump is complete when I look the SQL file.

Do you know a tip to know what happens ?

Thanks !

Comment: the command you are executing looks weird, you are passing a file to pg_dump which is supposed to dump a database into a file, not load it. the arrow should be the other way around (`>` instead of `<`, meaning dump the standard output of the comand to filename `mydump.sql`). also in what I suppose is the output of the command, I see no table definitions? are you sure this is the right database?

Comment: Yes you're right, thats the wrong command.
So I use  psql -U user database < dump.sql and it worked.
But I've got some strange errors like :

CREATE EXTENSION
ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql

or 

WARNING:  no privileges could be revoked for "public"
REVOKE
WARNING:  no privileges could be revoked for "public"
REVOKE
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "public"
GRANT
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "public"
GRANT

Have you ever see this ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: you should do the dumps/restores as `postgres` users, otherwise you will have to do a lot of permissions mangling.

Comment: Like that ?
psql -U postgres database < dump.sql

Comment: yes. But you still have to specify the database with `-d` option.

Comment: It returns me : psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

Comment: yes, that's expected. you either run dump/psql as the `postgres` user (sudo su - postgres`) or add password to postgres user (not recommended)

Comment: I've done a : postgres=# grant all privileges on database mydatabase to myuser; It should be enough, isn't it ?

Comment: Hmm it worked better (no error / warning in the sql import). But when I access the tables I still having : PostgreSQL said: permission denied for relation blog_article

Comment: for which user?

Comment: Ah...sorry, I try with my new user to access tables, not postgres. But I've done grant all permissions on him.

Comment: if the new database does not have the same roles, easiest way to resolve this is to change the ownership of tables to your user e.g `alter table <name> owner to <user>`

Comment: My bad it looks that my software had a refresh trouble, thank you very much for your help Uku Loskit !

Answer (score 1):

Dump and restore operations are best performed as `postgres` user. The easiest way to achieve this is to become the `postgres` UNIX user.

The initial command had the mistake of confusing `pg_dump` with `psql`.